# Getting the value of a link by Javascript

Tags: javascript, get

Here is the situation: I have a link of a page that gives only 1 or 0;
http://www.mybilet.com/connectors/functionAjax.php?islem=getBosDoluKoltuk&serverId=228&showtimeId=46666

Page is not mine. 
So I want to build an alarm system in another page according to this value. i.e. if the value is 1, the page plays a music. How can I get this value and write the if statement in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request the page synchronously via an `XMLHttpRequest`, then do the `if` statement.

E.g., roughly:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://www.mybilet.com/connectors/functionAjax.php?islem=getBosDoluKoltuk&serverId=228&showtimeId=46666", false) // Passing false as the last argument makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);

if(request.responseText == '1') {
    // Play music
}
```

Ooh yes: as the other answer demonstrates, it’s a bit less fiddly if you use jQuery. But I reckon it’s good to get your hands dirty with some Real Man’s JavaScript once in a while :)

Comment: You'll need to use the MS Active X Object in IE6 IIRC (if you plan on supporting that browser)

Comment: Asynchronous, pah! That’s for trendy webdevs, with their t-shirts and their lattes and their social networking and their AJAX. In my day, we had IRC, and HTML forms. AND WE LIKED IT.

Comment: Note that synchronous XHRs often freeze up the whole browser until they complete: http://kellegous.com/ecrits/001096

Answer (score 6):

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (which I strongly suggest)

```
$.get("http://www.mybilet.com/connectors/functionAjax.php?islem=getBosDoluKoltuk&serverId=228&showtimeId=46666", function(number){
    if(number=="1"){
        //play music
    }
});
```

should to the trick.

Comment: You should change //play music to //annoy user ;)